# How to load a chart in a diferent page

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, chart.js

I have a chart that is being constructed on page x but I want to load that chart in page y. How do I do that?

I'm trying to use a service but it didn't work.

page x

```
chart = [];

this.chart = new Chart('canvas', {

    type: 'line',
    data: {
        labels: this.datas,
        datasets: [{
            label: 'Score',
            fill: false,
            backgroundColor: 'rgb(255, 99, 132)',
             borderColor: 'rgb(255, 99, 132)',
            data: this.score
         }
     }
})

this.fichasService.chart = this.chart;
```

page y

```
test = this.fichasService.chart;
```

```
<canvas id="canvas">{{test}}</canvas>
```

If I try to draw the chart on page x it works fine, but when a try to draw in the page y it didn't work.

Answer (score 1):

What I'll do is to refactor that graph as a component itself, so it could be reused everywhere easily.
Just declare a component with the logic you already have, and use 
`<canvas id="canvas">{{test}}</canvas>`

as component's template

Comment: Thanks for trying to help.  This answer is fairly general / generic - might be nice to provide some more specific details.